# How can I clear the terminal with other made-up commands?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, terminal

Usually when I'm working on the project and I want to clear the screen, sometimes I type faster and so `clear` becomes `claear, claer, ...etc`.

I make these typo's and then obviously the terminal does not recognize them so I have to slowly type clear again.

What would be a script that would do the following:

`if user_command in [claer, claear, ... etc]:
         clear the screen`

If my input is one of the items in the list, then I want to clear the screen.

Comment: Aliases.  But then you'll never get rid of that habit. _shrug_

Comment: press Ctrl+L.  Doesn't even clutter up `history`.

Comment: Oh wow I didn't even know about this Ctrl L trick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have three options.

1. Create aliases.

   In your `~/.bashrc` file, create aliases with all possible errors:

   ```
   alias claer='clear'
   alias claear='clear'
   alias clera='clear'
   ```

   If you want to create regexs for your aliases, good luck with that. Take a look [at this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25810741/how-to-use-regex-in-bash-aliases) and its answer to see that is better to learn typing than lose time creating an additional nightmare for you to handle.
2. Use <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> instead of typing `claer`
   `clera`
   `celar`
   `cleer`... I mean, `clear`
3. Migrate to`zsh` and trust that it will have all your `clear` typos indexed [on this feature](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Intro/intro_16.html). Additional info: [What does [nyae] mean in Zsh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/800182/what-does-nyae-mean-in-zsh)

Comment: haha i see what you did there, your answer is very claer to me , thanks